# python program doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to return some letter in a string and I don't understand why it doesn't work. In the string `"mldtmgm"` it should return **3** because the order `find` should return the sum of all the m in the string. It returns **0** and I dont know if it's because not good using `find` or something else.

```
def ex4(str4):

    someLetter = str4[ :1]
    return str4.find(someLetter)

print ex4("mldtmgm")
```

Comment: Describe your problem properly.

Comment: you can use `return str4.count(someLetter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str.find` finds the index of the item. You need to use `str.count`.

```
def ex4(str4):

    someLetter = str4[ :1]
    return str4.count(someLetter)

print ex4("mldtmgm")
```